# launch file error: cannot launch node of type [map_server/map_server]

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a launch file that contains:

```
<launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="map_server_node" args="/home/maysam/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/mit/map.yaml"/>
</launch>
```

But the output is:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [map_server/map_server]: can't locate node [map_server] in package [map_server]
```

I can run the node manually and successfully:

```
rosrun map_server map_server /home/maysam/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/mit/map.yaml
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126446/launch-file-error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bmap_server/map_server%5D/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-02-05**:
what command you are using to run launch file ?

**Comment by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on 2014-02-06**:
roslaunch myfile.launch

**Comment by [dido_yf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21158/dido_yf/) on 2014-12-18**:
hello, I have exactly the same problem with you. Did you solve this problem? Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try this way  http://answers.ros.org/question/9379/roslaunch-and-map_server/?answer=13602#post-id-13602

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0